# XSLT split into multiple HTML files

Tags: html, xml, xslt, split

I'm quite a beginner with XSLT and I would like to split an XML file into multiple HTML files according to a specific attribute that is in the XML file.

Here is a sample of my XML file :

```
<article>
<div>
<paragraph>text text text</paragraph>
</div>
<div class="zoologie">
<def>this is a definition</def>
<def>this is another definition</def>
<example>this is a first example</example>
<example>this is a second example</example>
</div>
</article>

<article>
<div>
<paragraph>text text text</paragraph>
</div>
<div class="médecine">
<def>this is a definition</def>
<def>this is another definition</def>
<example>this is a first example</example>
<example>this is a second example</example>
</div>
</article>

<article>
<div>
<paragraph>text text text</paragraph>
</div>
<div class="zoologie">
<def>this is a definition</def>
<def>this is another definition</def>
<example>this is a first example</example>
<example>this is a second example</example>
</div>
</article>
```

What I would like to obtain is one HTML file that group togheter all articles with the same attribute class. For instance, one HTML file named zoologie.html that gather all the articles containing the attribute class="zoologie". And another HTML file named médecine.html that gather all articles with the attribute class="médecine". I have tried something with the split function but it won't work. I'd be grateful if you could help me with this.
Thanks,
Flo

Comment: Can you use an XSLT 2.0 processor and `xsl:result-document` or do you use an XSLT 1.0 processor that supports an extension to create multiple documents with one stylesheet?

Comment: I can use an XSLT 2.0 processor

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic XSLT 2.0 construct:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="article" group-by="div/@class">
  <xsl:result-document href="{current-grouping-key()}.xml">
    <articles>
      <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
    </articles>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

XSLT 1.0 doesn't have any built-in ability to do grouping or to generate multiple output files, but some 1.0 processors may have vendor extensions that help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It didn't work actually. I don't know why. For my goal, I had to use another method which consisted in selecting another attribute with the different values I wanted. I was then able to generate an HTML file for each. I had a deadline to meet and I couldn't afford to think any longer about a way to use the split function. Thanks again.